# What does `u` at the end of a number mean?

Tags: c, embedded

I know `0xFF` is hex. What is `u`?

```
#define PDL_ADC_10_MODE_SINGLE 0x00000001u
```

Comment: You should have searched it on google first.

Comment: @CuriousSid Single letter suffixes are sometimes hard to search on Google.

Answer (score 6):

When ending a number literal, it means that the number is `unsigned`